# jquery association array

Tags: jquery, arrays

Need a little help with what I'm sure is fairly easy jquery

I have the following repeating markup (several list items)

```
<li>
<div class="answer">
<p><select class="dropdown">
..options..
</select></p>
</div>
<div class="commentBox">
..content..
</div>
</li>
```

Depending on the value of the selected option when the pages loads, the "commentBox" will be shown/hidden.

I have tried the following jquery

```
var dd = $('.dropdown');
var com = $('.commentBox');


dd.each(dd, function(n, val){
if($(this).val() == 'whatever'){
   com[n].setStyle('display', 'none');
}
});
```

I get an error "b.apply is not a function"

So in my head, how it should work - if it's the first select dropdown, show/hide the first "commentBox" div. If it's the second dropdown then show/hide the second "commentBox" div. And so on.

I think I have got in a mess trying various jquery techniques so I am sure there are dozens of possibilities here.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're passing an extra (first) parameter to `each`.
`each` only takes the set as the first parameter when called statically.
In other words:

```
$.each(dd, function() { ... });
```

or

```
dd.each(function() { ... });
```

---

Note that you can make your code clearer by changing it to

```
$(this).closest('li').find('.commentBox').hide();
```

Comment: @jitter: Wrong; it isn't.  Try it.  Write `var a = $('a'); a.each(a, console.log)` in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

When [calling `.each()` like that](http://api.jquery.com/each/), you give it only one argument, the `function`.

```
dd.each(function(n, val){
    if($(this).val() == 'whatever'){
       com[n].setStyle('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Or you can pass 2 arguments if you [call `jQuery.each` like this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
$.each(dd, function(n, val){
    if($(this).val() == 'whatever'){
       com[n].setStyle('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

This second version is for iterating over any type of collection.

You were combining the two.

---

**EDIT:**  I guess I better explain that `setStyle` is in the OP's code, and is not the immediate cause of the issue at hand.

I have no way of knowing if OP extended the DOM elements with additional methods. As such, I can only assume that the placement of such a method is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var dd = $('.dropdown'),
    com = $('.commentBox');

dd.each(function(n, ele) {
    if( $(ele).val() == 'one') {
        com.eq(n).css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

used `.eq(n)` instead of `[n]` the latter would yield the DOM node while mine yields a jQuery object on which you can call `css()` (as you see I switched from `setStyle` what is that function anyway to `css()`).

---

Using the enhancement suggested by Slakks you end up with this better readable piece of code

```
$('.dropdown').each(function(n, ele){
    var $ele = $(ele);
    if ($ele.val() == "one")
        $ele.closest('li').find('.commentBox').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, really fast responses! And some handy tips in there for me as well.

Comment: you actually should accept SLaks answer as he provides an explanation why your `.each()` call was wrong and proposed the nice simplification I just reused in my second part of the answer

Comment: @jitter - I'd suggest not using the version that you gave based on SLaks' answer. Can't be sure without testing, but I'd guess that it would be less efficient to do a separate `.closest()` and `.find()` for (potentially) each iteration in the loop.

Comment: Well in terms of efficiency there can be still done very much. e.g. providing a context not search the whole page + restricting to selects `$('#ID_of_UL select.dropdown')`.

Comment: @jitter - I agree. I just meant comparing your first example to the second, I'd lean toward the first. Would need to test to be sure though. Overall, I'd lean the most toward OP's original solution of accessing the DOM element directly, but I'd do `com[ n ].style.display = 'none';` instead.